# Font styling issue in IE

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a list that contains fonts using angular directive

```
<li  ng-repeat='o in options'><button class='btn btn-blue checked-dropdown' style='font-family: {{o.css}}; width: 100%' type='button' ng-click='action($event, o.css)'><i ng-if='o.active' class='fa fa-check'></i>{{o.name}}</button></li>

  options: [
            { name: 'Sans-Serif', css: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' },
            { name: 'Serif', css: "'times new roman', serif" },
            { name: 'Wide', css: "'arial black', sans-serif" },
            { name: 'Narrow', css: "'arial narrow', sans-serif" },
            { name: 'Comic Sans MS', css: "'comic sans ms', sans-serif" },
            { name: 'Courier New', css: "'courier new', monospace" },
            { name: 'Garamond', css: 'garamond, serif' },
            { name: 'Georgia', css: 'georgia, serif' },
            { name: 'Tahoma', css: 'tahoma, sans-serif' },
            { name: 'Trebuchet MS', css: "'trebuchet ms', sans-serif" },
            { name: "Helvetica", css: "'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" },
            { name: 'Verdana', css: 'verdana, sans-serif' },
            { name: 'Proxima Nova', css: 'proxima_nova_rgregular' }
        ]
```

when I click on button then the full font list is shown with their css applied on it. 
It is working fine in Chrome but in IE only the font name is shown in plain text 
  [IE Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNTJk.png)      [Chrome Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBxnd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attaching model value to specific property in style attr, you can make use of ng-style directive & call the function on ng-style as:  `ng-style = "mystyle($index)"`

```
$scope.mystyle = function(index){
      return {
        'font-family': $scope.options[index].css,
         'width': "100%"
      }
    }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ew8VyCWojAiyCqaU55qM?p=preview